# ListView Item selection Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-listview

I have a listview in that i want when my activity starts then the first item will have background and the other items don't have any background.After that if the user selects any other item then the background of that particular item will now be blue and the rest don't have any background.Please help me on this.

My **layout_effect.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_focused="true">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
    </shape>
</item>
    <item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#00a7eb" />
    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

My GetView Code where i am setting the default Background

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 
        if(position == 0){

            vi.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selection_effect);
            vi.setSelected(true);

            }
        }
```

Any my onclickListner of the listview

```
onewayListView .setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Clicked", 1000).show();
        }
    });
```

My Listview xml

```
<ListView
            android:id="@+id/lvDepartures"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/selection_effect"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
```

Please help me how could i solve this problem i am stucked in it from last 1day.

Answer (score 19):

For doing this what you can do is create a selector and apply it to parent view of your `row.xml`

- **Define color in strings.xml**

  `<color name="blue">#009FE3</color>`
- **Create a selector**

  ```
  <item android:drawable="@color/blue" android:state_activated="true" />
  <item android:drawable="@color/blue" android:state_focused="true" />
  ```

Now apply it as `android:background="@drawable/row_selector"` for parent view of your row.

- **Set ListView as CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE in java code**

  `listview.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);`
- **And finally setAdapter to your ListView.**

  `listview.setAdapter(adapter);`
- **For selection of default item in ListView use,**

  `listview.setItemChecked(position, true);`

[I had created a demo example for the same you can download it from my github](https://github.com/lalit3686/ListSelectorActivity)

Comment: so what for the default selected item when the activity starts

Comment: No, just after calling `listview.setAdapter(adapter)`

Comment: onewaydata=new OneWayFlightResult(this, flightData);        
onewayListView.setAdapter(onewaydata);

Comment: Oh my GOD!!!, If you don't know `position` in ListView then you are not supposed to code further, read the docs!

Comment: onewaydata=new OneWayFlightResult(this, flightData);        
    onewayListView.setItemChecked(0, true);
    onewayListView.setAdapter(onewaydata); ihave done this but it is not working it is selecting the first one by default when the activity starts rest is working fine

Comment: Well as you have given `0` in `onewayListView.setItemChecked(0, true); ` its obvious that it will selected first by default

Comment: but the background effect is not appearing for the default one

Comment: I must add to my selector android:state_activated and android:state_focused. But why android:state_seleted not work???

Answer (score 1):

Create a selector for listview

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed_yellow"
          android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused_orange"
          android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal_green" />
</selector>
```

`setOnItemClickListener` write the following function

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                ""+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Go through this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2011/10/android-listview-tutorial/

Comment: please see my layout_effect.xml .I am using this so first one is selected default but when i am clicking other item in the list view the property of default selected item remains same that is the problem

Answer (score 0):

OnListItem click pass the selected position to the adapter and set the adapter again 
and in adapter check if selected position then set the background otherwise does not set the background.

Answer (score 0):

you should check this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 
    if(position%2 == 0){

        vi.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selection_effect);
        vi.setSelected(true);

        }else{

         // set another background.

        }
    }
```

Comment: please see my layout_effect.xml .I am using this so first one is selected default but when i am clicking other item in the list view the property of default selected item remains same that is the problem

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but try putting `listView.setSelection(position);` in listview's `setOnItemClickListener`

Answer (score 0):

Remove your default list-selector in your listview or set it as null:

```
   <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:listSelector="@null" >
    </ListView>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lvDepartures"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/selection_effect"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>