# Listview default item selected

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview as show below:

```
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/profile_picture"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:background="#f7f7f7"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:entries="@array/navigation_drawer"
        android:listSelector="@color/navigation_selector"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"/>
```

and i want to make the first item in the list is selected, i have tried list.setSelection(0), also setItemChecked but none of them works.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need state- aware backgrounds on your list items as described in some of the answers here:

[ListView Item selection Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18118839/listview-item-selection-android)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for something like a [Spinner](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html)?

If you read the description for setSelection (in the case of a [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setSelection%28int%29)) you will notice:

*"Sets the currently selected item. **If in touch mode, the item will not be selected** but it will still be positioned appropriately. If the specified selection position is less than 0, then the item at position 0 will be selected."*

**However** what you could do is set the item as selected with setSelection, and just set the list item's background drawable to something of a different color to indicate that it is selected.

Why does it work this way? Well, setSelection is more of an accessibility feature, or in the case of a phone with a cursor ball (like the original G1 android phone), it shows what it selected on the screen if it was selected with an input other than the touch screen.  So, you're not going to see anything if you use it normally.