# How to highlight selected gridview items

Tags: android, gridview

im using gridview `CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL` to select multiple items(images) in my gridview .

I used `MultiChoiceModeListener` to achieve this, the problem is selected items are not get highlighted

Selector xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
   <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@color/green"/>
   <item android:state_pressed="true" 
          android:drawable="@color/blue"/> <!-- pressed state -->
   <item android:state_focused="true" 
          android:drawable="@color/blue"/> <!-- focused state -->
   <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/> <!-- default state --> 

   </selector>
```

When I touch an item it get covered with blue (i think this happens bcoz i used `gridView.setDrawSelectorOnTop(true);` )...as soon as i lift my finger blue color get removed.

I want the selected items to get `highlighted` with `semi transparent blue` color and it should stay highlighted until I deselect the item.

Java Code:

```
public class HappyFragment extends ParentFragment {

    public HappyImageAdapter imageAdapter;
    private List<ResolveInfo> mApps;
    GridView gridView;

     public static HappyFragment newInstance() {
         HappyFragment fragment = new HappyFragment();
         return fragment;
     }

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

//          if ((savedInstanceState != null) && savedInstanceState.containsKey(KEY_CONTENT)) {
//            //  mContent = savedInstanceState.getString(KEY_CONTENT);
//          }
     }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.happy_fragment_layout, container, false);
           //  ImageView iv= (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1); 
             gridView = (GridView)view.findViewById(R.id.gvHappy);

            // Instance of ImageAdapter Class
             imageAdapter = new HappyImageAdapter(getActivity());
            gridView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
            gridView.setChoiceMode(GridView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
            gridView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new MultiChoiceModeListener());
            gridView.setDrawSelectorOnTop(true);
            gridView.setSelector(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gridview_selector));

            gridView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), String.valueOf(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                }
            }); 

            gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,int position, long id) {
                    if(BaseActivity.isinint) { // check if any app cares for the result
                        int ImageResourse=imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position];
                    Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://dragonflymobile.stickers.lifestickers/" + ImageResourse);

                        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND, path); //Create a new intent. First parameter means that you want to send the file. The second parameter is the URI pointing to a file on the sd card. (openprev has the datatype File)

                        ((Activity)getActivity()).setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, shareIntent); //set the file/intent as result
                        ((Activity)getActivity()).finish(); //close your application and get back to the requesting application like GMail and WhatsApp
                        return; //do not execute code below, not important
                    } else {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), PreviewActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("Image Int", imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            });
            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
         //   outState.putString(KEY_CONTENT, mContent);
        }

        //multi select mode codes
        public class MultiChoiceModeListener implements GridView.MultiChoiceModeListener {
            public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                mode.setTitle("Select Items");
                mode.setSubtitle("One item selected");
                return true;
            }

            public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                return true;
            }

            public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
                return true;
            }

            public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            }

            public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position, long id, boolean checked) {
                int selectCount = gridView.getCheckedItemCount();
                switch (selectCount) {
                case 1:
                    mode.setSubtitle("One item selected");
                    break;
                default:
                    mode.setSubtitle("" + selectCount + " items selected");
                    break;
                }
            }
}
}
```

Comment: I had done that for ListView with `CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE` you can try it for `CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL` for GridView, just have a look at it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18119283/726863)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

okay i found this 3rd party library which do exactly this with less code 
here is the github [link](https://github.com/ManuelPeinado/MultiChoiceAdapter)

and here is a gridview with images tutorial [link](https://github.com/ManuelPeinado/MultiChoiceAdapter/wiki/Gallery-tutorial)

Answer (score 7):

just follow this,

1.put your grid view child item in **FrameLayout**

2.give FrameLayout property **android:foreground="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"**

that's it... no need to use extra library

Comment: Just as a note, use `android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"` in case you want to change the highlight color behind the grid item and not in front.

Answer (score 2):

In case that anyone wants a solution without thrid library just put this code inside

onItemCheckedStateChanged (here gv is your gridView name)

```
    if(checked){
                View tv = (View) gv.getChildAt(position);
                tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            }else{
                View tv = (View) gv.getChildAt(position);
                tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            }
```

Comment: Perfect solution..Instead of `Color.RED` I've used `getResources().getColor(R.color.borderColor)`  and   `<color name="borderColor">#28AABA</color>` . This gives the same color as in gallery. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
gridView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(android.view.ActionMode actionMode, int i, long l, boolean b) {
        // Capture total checked items
        final int checkedCount = gridView.getCheckedItemCount();
        // Set the CAB title according to total checked items
        actionMode.setTitle(checkedCount + " Selected");

        if(gridView.getChildAt(i).isSelected()) {
            gridView.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF4081"));
        }else{
            gridView.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#b1e76905"));
        }
        // Calls toggleSelection method from ListViewAdapter Class
        adapter.toggleSelection(i);
    }
```