# Listview item initial selection

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview, navigation-drawer

I have a nav drawer that navigates between three fragments, when I start my app fragment 1 is displayed.  In this case I want to have the first item in the nav drawer list initially selected.  I followed this link: [ListView Item selection Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18118839/listview-item-selection-android), based on this I have the following in my adapter,

```
if(position==0){
      listview.setItemChecked(position, true);
   }
```

and it works correctly, the first item on the list is pre selected.  However, when I click on another item on the list it is selected but the first item is till selected.

I have tried unselecting the item by setting `listview.setItemChecked(position, false);` but this doesn't work for me, so I have the initial selection working fine but I can't include it unless I can deselect it when the user selects a different item.

Can anyone help?

***EDIT - GET VIEW ADDED ***

```
  @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView==null){
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                    context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.nav_item_layout, null);
        }
        imgIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nav_item_image);
        txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nav_item_text);



        if(position==0)
        {
            drawerList.setItemChecked(0,true);
        }

        if(drawerList.isItemChecked(position)){
            if(position!=0){
                drawerList.setItemChecked(0, false);

            }
            imgIcon.setImageResource(selectedIconArray[position]);
            txtTitle.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        }else{
            imgIcon.setImageResource(unselectedIconArray[position]);
            txtTitle.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#949494"));
        }
        txtTitle.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getTitle());

        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: post your getView method please

Comment: @SirKuryaki do you have any ideas as to what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With:

```
    if(position==0)
    {
        drawerList.setItemChecked(0,true);
    }
```

You're forcing the row 0 to be always checked. You have to remove both setItemChecked from inside the getViewMethod.  Call setItemChecked when you're setting the Adapter to your ListView.

Comment: as simple as that...very helpful!