# How to Highlight single item in Listview

Tags: android, arrays, listview, android-listview, android-adapter

When i click any item in listview, the item is highlighting but when i click the second item , it is also highlighting. i want only one item to be highlighted.

**menu.xml**

```
<ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:background="#50332b"
            />
```

**Menulist.java**

```
    lstcategory = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);
    lstcategory.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    lstcategory.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
                    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
```

Comment: which position item you wanna highlight?

Comment: the item which i am clicking in listview should be highlighted

Comment: @tamil arasan: use a boolean flag and set thatto false after first item selection.

Comment: Here is my answer you can check it - http://stackoverflow.com/a/18119283/726863

Comment: check listview `position`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add boolean flag in your pojo class say

```
Boolean isSelected;
```

apply getter and setters in it.
initially set all the values for isSelected = false so that no list item is selected

now during onItem click set the current Object's isSelected to true 
like this

within the onItemClick apply this

```
OnItemClickListener listViewOnItemClick = new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View arg1, int position, long id) {

for(int i =0;i  < lstcategory.size();i++}{
lstcategory.get(i).setIsSelected(false);
}

lstcategory.get(position).setIsSelected(true); 
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
};
```

now in getview of your adapter class check if the lists item isChecked or not.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final View view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.item_list, null);

    if (lstcategory.get(position).getIsSelected()) {
        // set selected your color
    }else{
       //set default color
    }


    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**You need to keep track the position of the current selected element:**

Example:

```
OnItemClickListener listViewOnItemClick = new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View arg1, int position, long id) {
            mSelectedItem = position;
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};
```

**And override the getView method of your adapter:**

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final View view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.item_list, null);

    if (position == mSelectedItem) {
        // set selected your color
    }else{
       //set default color
    }


    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create a row_selector in drawable folder

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@color/white" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/white" />
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@color/white" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/light_gray" />
</selector>
```

Now apply it as  android:background="@drawable/row_selector" for parent view of your row.

**Set ListView as CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE in java code**

listview.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);